# Regasm failing for administrator account

Tags: dll, vb6, regasm, dllregistration

Operating system: Windows XP Service Pack 3
Framework: Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.0.50727

Command Prompt started as Administrator

```
<framework directory>\regasm /codebase Hps.Exchange.PosGateway.Client.dll /tlb
or
<framework directory>\regasm /codebase Hps.Exchange.PosGateway.Client.dll
```

operating system returns:

```
RegAsm : error RA0000 : An error occurred while writing the registration 
information to the registry. You must have administrative credentials to 
perform this task.  Contact your system administrator for assistance
```

I do a set from the command prompt and it shows username=Administrator

Thanks Guys

Comment: It's possible that something (virus or corporate policy, for example) has changed your registry permissions. Try resetting to the default using [Solving setup errors by using the SubInACL tool to repair file and registry permissions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2006/09/04/739820.aspx).

Comment: Holi Moli create it as an answer.  Your my new hero.  Do you know how to cook as well :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might fail if for some reason you don't have the correct permission to the registry. This could be caused by a number of things, such as corporate policy or a virus/malware. Try resetting to the default using [Solving setup errors by using the SubInACL tool to repair file and registry permissions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2006/09/04/739820.aspx).

The basic gist from that page (in case the link breaks in the future) is to download [SubInACL](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=E8BA3E56-D8FE-4A91-93CF-ED6985E3927B&displaylang=en) and then run the following commands:

```
subinacl /subkeyreg HKEY_CURRENT_USER /grant=administrators=f /grant=system=f /grant=restricted=r /grant=YOURUSERNAME=f /setowner=administrators
subinacl /keyreg HKEY_CURRENT_USER /grant=administrators=f /grant=system=f /grant=restricted=r /grant=YOURUSERNAME=f /setowner=administrators
subinacl /subkeyreg HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE /grant=administrators=f /grant=system=f /grant=users=r /grant=everyone=r /grant=restricted=r /setowner=administrators
subinacl /keyreg HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE /grant=administrators=f /grant=system=f /grant=users=r /grant=everyone=r /grant=restricted=r /setowner=administrators
subinacl /subkeyreg HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT /grant=administrators=f /grant=system=f /grant=users=r /setowner=administrators
subinacl /keyreg HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT /grant=administrators=f /grant=system=f /grant=users=r /setowner=administrators
subinacl /subdirectories %programfiles%\ /grant=administrators=f /grant=system=f /grant=users=e
subinacl /subdirectories %windir%\ /grant=administrators=f /grant=system=f /grant=users=e
```

However, I recommend visiting the linked page as it provides more details and caveats.

Comment: Does make you wonder if the problem can reoccur though.  I didn't see anything on that page that suggests what causes this condition.

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to say without knowing more about the machine. If it does recur, a tool like ProcMon might be able to detect it.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem here, I solved it by running the x86 version of regasm, instead of the x64, so in instead of

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727>regasm.exe
```

use

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727>regasm.exe
```